# Confidence interval for Mann-Whitney test (Hodges–Lehmann estimator)

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, minitab

Does anybody knows how to calculate the confidence interval using normal approximation for the Hodges-Lehmann estimator (median of Y-X)?

This is how Minitab performs calculation, but I cannot find formula behind it!

**Example**

Group 1: 0.8, 1.2, 1.4, 0.9, 1.0

Group 2: 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 0.7, 1.6

And below the result from Minitab which informs a CI of (-0,6998;0,3000) (How?)

> Point estimate for $\eta_1$ - $\eta_2$ is -0,2000
>
> 96,3 Percent CI for $\eta_1$ - $\eta_2$ is (-0,6998;0,3000)
>
> W = 23,0
>
> Test of $\eta_1 = \eta_2$ vs $\eta_1 \neq \eta_2$ is significant at 0,2017

Comment: Which group corresponds to X and which to Y?

Comment: @MichaelChernick X (group 1) and Y (group 2).

Comment: What makes you say that there's a normal approximation involved in this confidence interval?

Comment: @Glen_b Since IC is calculated over all differences between Y and X, it's not possible to have values with more than one decimal place. As you can see on Minitab output, it shows 4 decimal places for the lower value. Also, since it has ties when we consider all differences and it uses rank, normal aproximation is usually the approach.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning at all. I don't see how the fact that Minitab gave a value of -.6998 implies that anything anywhere was normal. When you say " normal aproximation is usually the approach" ... I don't think I've seen a normal approximation used for a Hodges Lehman interval, (certainly not with small n). What's the basis for your statement about Hodges Lehmann intervals? Is it a guess or do you know that's what Minitab did?

Comment: @Glen_b I don't know how minitab did, but I know Minitab uses normal approximation regardless of sample size. Calculating exact values in the present of ties is a chalange and that's one of reasons it always uses normal approximation

Comment: Do you have information from some manual that says anything about what normal approximation they're using, and where they're using it?  (e.g. normal approximation for the distribution of the test statistic under the null doesn't necessarily imply a normal approximation is generating the interval)

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, in the help page, it's said that they use normal approximation to calculate p-value. Since usually both p-value and confidence interval calculation share the same approach, it's most likely they are using normal approximation to calculate IC. http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/hypothesis-tests/nonparametrics-tests/calculating-mann-whitney-statistics/

Comment: I don't know for sure whether they use a normal approximation or "exact" procedure (nor can I find any obvious way to make sure, though [this page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat464/node/39#) is perhaps suggestive), but in any case both kinds of interval are detailed [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/non-parametric-tests/mann-whitney-test/mann-whitney-median-confidence-interval/).

Comment: @Glen_b those links shows how to calculate IC using Mann-Whitney tables. Apparently this is not the way that Minitab does. I found a reference in Minitab help pages to a article (see information in bottom: http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/basic-statistics/inference/how-to/two-samples/mann-whitney-test/methods-and-formulas/methods-and-formulas/). I got the article. i'll check how they are calculating this.